# How do you modify the fields output in Drupal's RSS Feeds

Tags: drupal, rss, view

Trying to modify the RSS feeds created by Views module in Drupal.

Since there are no 'theme_' hooks for the RSS feeds (rightfully as XML is theme-less), I need an alternate way to modify the fields that are output into the RSS, preferably using template.php if possible.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/format_rss_item/6 looks promising as that is where each row is created, but it doesn't

`node_feed()` is what collects the nodes, creates the additional fields, and then calls `format_rss_item()`.

Specifically, we need to remove the `dc:creator` element from the `$extra` array created in `node_feed()`

Comment: I found this link http://www.timtoon.com/2009/05/27/customizing-an-rss-feed-using-drupal-and-views/comment-page-1/#comment-4899 which mentions how to modify the output, but it looks to be very inefficient as it does an additional db query for each node in the feed.

Comment: Looking at the timtoon link, it requires creating a page view (instead of rss view) which is not feasable at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view, if you click on "style information" this will show you the template files used to create the feed. You can copy the template so that it is overridden for your view and remove dc:creator from the `$item_elements` array.

This is not particularly nice as you are modifying data in the theme layer, but it will do what you want.

Comment: This would have worked too, but we ended up using contemplate to style the content type that was in the feeds. 
I think this is the best solution at the moment as you can affect the exact RSS feeds you need, all of them or one of them.

Comment: $item_elements is not an array, you got to ereg_replace see [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/views-rss-post-date-removal)

Answer (score 4):

If you go into a specific content type, you can set the RSS display fields as per this post:

http://redfinsolutions.com/redfin-blog/show-hide-fields-views-generated-drupal-rss-feed

Answer (score 2):

I am adding another answer, as I have recently had to do this and managed to do it without modifying data in the theme layer.

You can add a preprocess function to your view. It is a bit of work though.

There are some [guidelines here](http://drupal.org/node/303586), but they are a bit confusing. Here is my summary of how to do this.

First make sure your modules weight is > views

Secondly copy the template you would like to add a preprocessor to to your modules directory. Rename it to be something in the list of templates in theming information.

Then edit hook theme like this (but change to use the existing view that you need to override.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  // Copy the exsisting views theme from the existing array.
  $override = $existing['views_view_row_rss'];
  // Add my preprocessor to the list of preprocess functions
  $override['preprocess functions'][] = 'mymodule_myfunction';
  // Point to a template so that this view will be used.
  $override['template'] = 'my_more_specific_template_name';
  $override['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'path');
  unset($override['file']);
  // Return your theme handler.
  return array('my_more_specific_template_name' => $override);
}
```

You should then be able to write your preprocess code in the function mymodule_myfunction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [Views Node Feed](http://drupal.org/project/views_node_feed) module to do this. It will let you completely write the XML that is output by Views for feeds.

Comment: This wold work but the module is still in development for Drupal 6 and does not fully implement the view_plugin_style Class's interface, giving errors.